# Meaning of capital gain distribution

Tags: united-states, taxes, capital-gain, capital-loss

How is capital gain distribution calculated?

1. I wonder what differences and relations are between capital gain
   distribution and capital gain/loss?

   Line 13 of IRS Form 1040 asks for capital gain and loss, but
   its instructions seem to say that capital gain distribution is reported on
   Line 13. I wonder if rigorously speaking, IRS messes up the
   difference between capital gain distribution  and capital gain/loss?
2. How is capital gain distribution related to whether capital gain/loss is realized or unrealized?

   Through 2011, I had been holding a mutual fund without selling it.
   So there is no realized capital gain or capital loss. I receive capital gain distribution at the end of the year.

   If capital gain distribution is calculated based on realized capital
   gain or capital loss, Why did I receive capital gain distribution?

   Does it mean that capital gain distribution is calculated based on
   unrealized instead of realized capital gain or capital loss?
3. Is capital gain distribution taken from my shares?

   I was talking to a representative of a brokery company, who said that capital gain distribution  is caculated based on my share
   values, but not taken from my shares.

   But I saw some definition on
   [investorwords](http://www.investorwords.com/707/capital_gains_distribution.html#ixzz1rqSBn12C) saying that "capital gains distributions reduce the value of the fund". Does it mean that it reduces the value per share?

   So I wonder if the two sayings are contrary to each
   other?
4. My capital gain distribution was automatically used for
   reinvestment. Do I need to report it on Line 13 of Form 1040?

   Does [investorwords](http://www.investorwords.com/707/capital_gains_distribution.html#ixzz1rqSBn12C) say no need, by"many funds allow automatic reinvestment
   of capital gains, instead of distribution. ... Also, these distributions
   are taxable income for the recipient, so funds that allow
   reinvestment instead of distribution are sometimes preferred by
   investors in high tax brackets."?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Edited in the light of comments and follow-on questions**

Your mutual fund manager buys and sells securities in pursuit of 
the investment strategies
of the fund as well as to invest new money coming in and to pay out investors wanting to take their money elsewhere. This results in capital gains and losses for the *fund*. 
The net capital gain is taxable income (at corporate rates)
to the *fund* unless the fund *distributes* the gains to the shareholders
in which case the investors have to pay the taxes on the gains
that they receive. For what happens if the fund experiences a 
net capital loss, 
see [this answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/14327/5760) to a related question.

You have to report the capital gains distributions from a mutual 
fund regardless of whether you chose to re-invest in the fund or 
received the distribution in cash, or had directed your broker 
(or the fund company) to reinvest the distribution into another 
fund etc. You do not report or pay taxes on any changes in 
the value of your mutual fund investment as share prices of the
securities of the fund fluctuate; only when you *sell* 
any shares do you have a capital gain or capital loss on that
portion of your investment.

With regard to your question about "taking from your shares", the value of
your mutual fund shares is determined by the net value of the underlying
securities held by the mutual fund plus any cash held by the mutual fund.
When the mutual fund makes a capital gain (or dividend) distribution to
its shareholders, the mutual fund assets decline in value by the amount
of the distribution because that money is out the door. Consequently
the share value falls proportionally. For those who choose to re-invest
in the fund, they get to buy the fund at the reduced value. Put another
way, suppose you bought 100 shares at $8 per share on January 1, 2010.
Your *basis* (the amount invested) is thus $800.
In 2010, the net capital gains of the fund were 0 and no distribution
was made. In late 2011, the mutual fund shares were valued at $10
and so you have a *unrealized gain* of $200, not reportable, not
taxable etc. But suppose that during 2011, the fund sold some securities
for a capital gain, and so in late 2011, it made a distribution of 
$1 per share and "sent you" $100. After this distribution, 
each of your shares would have value only $9, and your net wealth
would be $900 in shares plus $100 in cash. If you have chosen to
reinvest the $100 in new shares, you would be buying 100/9 shares
at $9 dollars each so that you now own (100+100/9) shares valued
at $9 each, making your net wealth $(100 + 100/9)x9 = $1000 just 
as before. No change in value, but you have to report the $100
received on your tax return and pay taxes on the
$100 received, even though you reinvested the whole amount.
But **now** your **basis** in the fund is $900; the amount
$800 you originally invested plus the $100 you plowed back 
into the fund.  If at a later time, you decide to get out of
the mutual fund, and the share price is still $9 that day,
you will get $1000 for your 100+100/9 = 111.1111111 shares.
**Only $100 of that amount is taxable since your basis is
$900**. The point of JoeTaxpayer's comment below is that far
too many people forget to add the reinvested amounts into
the basis and say "I put in $800, got $1000 back, and so
I owe taxes on $200 profit" quite forgetting that they have
actually invested $900, or equivalently, that they have already
paid taxes on $100 of the $200, and so taxes are owed
only on the remaining $100. Now, it is true (as the comment by @dave_thompso _085 points out in a comment) that starting in 2012, mutual funds were required to track your basis (including reinvested distributions) but at least two major mutual fund houses have taken the position that this applies only to the shares bought from 2012 onwards. They won't go back though their records to determine the basis for the shares held directly by the investor (i.e. not through a brokerage) prior to 2012. They *do* provide paper forms that the investor can fill out telling them the basis of shares held prior to 2012. (Whether they check if the information provided matches with their records is something I don't know.) Alternatively, when the shares are sold, one can report the basis *not* included on the 1099-DIV in Part II of Schedule D directly to the IRS; just be sure to follow the same rules (FIFO, LIFO, or Average Cost) as you told the mutual fund that you wanted them to follow in determining the basis of the shares sold.

(note from JoeTaxpayer added) - If reinvested, you must add the $100 to your basis, the same as if 'new' money came in. This point is often missed and tax paid twice in error.

There have been several years in the recent past where mutual
funds declined in value over the course of a year (unrealized
capital loss for the share holder) but still paid capital gains
distributions which had to be reported and on which tax had to
be paid.

Comment: +1, I added one note to clarify what I though was an important point. Hope you're ok with that.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer: For your added part "If reinvested, you must add the $100 to your basis, the same as if 'new' money came in. This point is often missed and tax paid twice in error." (1) What is "basis"? What is a position then? Are they the same? (2) How is "tax paid twice" like? Why treating reinvestment as new money coming in will avoid "tax paid twice"? Thanks!

Comment: I will stand by for a bit and let Dilip add to the answer if he wishes. Else, I'll update. it's too long to add as comment. (I'm sure he knows my train of thought on this)

Comment: @Tim Thanks. I revised my answer to incorporate answers to your additional questions. If you like it, please consider accepting it so that this question is laid to rest.

Comment: Dilip nailed it. Great explanation.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: If I understand you correctly, istributions used for reinvestment are still taxed in the same way as if they were not reinvested. I wonder why "(capital gains distributions) are taxable income for the recipient, so funds that allow reinvestment instead of distribution are sometimes preferred by investors in high tax brackets." (from http://www.investorwords.com/707/capital_gains_distribution.html#ixzz1sA84WQB6)

Comment: @Tim I have no idea why that link is saying what it does (I am, alas, not an investor in a high tax bracket). In my limited experience, funds that closed (and would not take on new investors because the managers could not handle the inflow) nevertheless allowed current investors to reinvest the distributions. Maybe some closed funds (hedge funds?) do not allow reinvestment of distributions, and a big investor who gets several millions in distributions cannot plow that money back into the fund but must take it elsewhere?

Comment: Starting with 2012, the year this A was written, (US) mutual funds have been required to keep track of your basis (including reinvested distributions) and state it on the 1099-B that reports your sale (technically redemption), and you were instructed to copy the 1099-B to your tax return (8949), which made it quite difficult to forget :-) (This basis reporting requirement started a year earlier for stocks, IIRC including ETFs, and over the next several years for bonds and some other things.)