# Starting non-retirement investment account

Tags: united-states, investing, starting-out-investing, investment-strategies

I would like to start investing in a non-retirement account. I have:

- A 401k through my employer I'm contributing to with Vanguard
- A 529 for my two daughters, three and five, I'm contributing to with Vanguard
- No debt
- A six month emergency fund
- A couple thousand "play money" I would like to invest for at least one year

The money is just sitting there and I would like to keep up with inflation at the least. Vanguard gives me the option to add a new brokerage account for "stocks, bonds, ETFs, CDs, and non-Vanguard mutual funds."

Are ETFs a good option? If so, how would taxes work? For example, if I invest $2,000, it returns 10% in one year and I don't withdraw anything, around how much would I owe on the $2,200? If I withdraw the entire $2,200 around how much would I owe?

Comment: The I in IRA stands for **Individual**. Your employer may be agreeing to put monthly deposits into your IRA account with Vanguard instead of including these amounts in your take-home pay, but other than this, your employer has **no** connection with your IRA. It is **you**, the **Individual** who has an IRA account with Vanguard.

Comment: Used the wrong term - updated.

Comment: For some answers to the questions in your last paragraph, read [this answer](http://money.stackexchange.com/a/15298/5760) posted some time ago.

Answer (score 1):

You pay taxes on any gains you make after selling, so if you buy and hold you won't pay taxes (and you should hold for more than a year so that it gets taxed at the long-term rate, not the short-term rate).

I like ETFs, there are some good ones Vanguard offers that are fairly broad, or you can use something like www.Betterment.com which invests in a diversified portfolio of ETFs (and includes things like automatic re-balancing and tax-loss harvesting).

Comment: Are there no dividends anymore? Wouldn't those be taxable distributions?